# How to get ActiveDirectory Group email addresses

Tags: asp.net, search, filter, get, active-directory

I am getting groups names from active directories. but I need mail addresses of these groups like gr-all@blabla... or gr-it-software@blabla...

here is my code for getting groups..

```
string groupName = String.Empty;
            int startIndex = 0;
            DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://blabla");
            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(de);
            searcher.Filter = "(&(&(objectClass=group)(objectcategory=group))(name=*" + pSearchText + "*))"; //this contain filter for adgroups from textbox
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
            SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll();
            foreach (SearchResult result in results)
            {
                de = result.GetDirectoryEntry();//de object has a lot of properties but not include e mail address, or it is include I can't see that. 
                groupName = de.Name;
                startIndex = groupName.IndexOf('=') + 1;
                groupName = groupName.Substring(startIndex, groupName.Length - startIndex);
                groupNames.Add(groupName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String Email = result.GetDirectoryEntry.Properties("mail").Value
```